# Clear only a section in turtle

Tags: python, graphics, turtle-graphics

I am trying to use some turtle and want to update the text shown on screen. my code looks something like this. you can assume when I will run it, it will give me the disturbed output as at the place of `i` many values would be printed.

```
for i in range(n):
    turtle.write(' Something  {i} '.format(i))
```

My screen has a few more graphics so if I will use `clear` it seems to clear all screen. I just want to change the value in mentioned code nothing else. There would be some conditions( You don't need to worry about them. ) in for loop based on that turtle need to write something {i}.

Answer (score 0):

To clear a portion of your drawing, use different turtles to draw the components and only call `clear()` on the turtle whose scribblings you want to remove:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT_SIZE = 18
FONT = ('Arial', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')

screen = Screen()

marker_turtle = Turtle()
marker_turtle.hideturtle()
marker_turtle.penup()
marker_turtle.sety(150 - FONT_SIZE/2)

marker_turtle.write("I will now draw a circle", align='center', font=FONT)

graphics_turtle = Turtle()
graphics_turtle.speed('slowest')
graphics_turtle.circle(150)
graphics_turtle.hideturtle()

marker_turtle.clear()

screen.exitonclick()
```